# What are the fastest ways to calculate class number of number fields?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, number-fields

Given a number field $K$, which approaches help us to calculate the class number $h(K)$ of $K$?

I am aware that the question is broad but any argument would be helpful.

Some basic approaches I know:

For a imaginary quadratic number field $K$ with discriminant $D$, we can look for the number of positive definite reduced binary quadratic forms of discriminant $D$.

For a real quadratic number field $K$, we can use continued fraction expansions to find fundemantal units of $K$ and then use Minkowski's bound(or any other similar bounds) to find $h(K)$. We can also calculate the class number of an imaginary quadratic number field using Minkowski's bound.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/algorithms-to-compute-the-class-number